# How to matched object from main image with the template sub-Image using normxcorr2

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I try to determine the coordinates of a puzzle piece on the original image using the normxcorr2 function. Then I draw a rectangle on the correspondence of the two elements. Unfortunately, I notice that the coordinates that this match has given me are not good. Could someone have an idea how to improve the use of this feature and get some better results.
The puzzle piece has the name "cpiece" and the original picture has the name "bild"

```
clear all;
close all;
clc


cpiece = im2gray(imread('cpiece1.jpg'));
bild = im2gray(imread('original.jpg'));

figure(1)
montage({bild,cpiece})

c = normxcorr2(cpiece,bild);
figure(2)
surf(c)
shading flat

[ypeak,xpeak] = find(c==max(c(:)));

yoffSet = ypeak-size(cpiece,1);
xoffSet = xpeak-size(cpiece,2);

figure(3)
imshow(bild)
drawrectangle(gca,'Position',[xoffSet,yoffSet,size(cpiece,2),size(cpiece,1)],'FaceAlpha',0);
```

[image: image with rectangle]

[image: original image]

[image: puzzle piece]

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the problem returns back to the  quality of your template image, And Check if the scales between original image and the template are exactly the same

Comment: I'm just taking this puzzle piece to explain the problem. But I did not have the same problem  with all puzzle piece. For the mostly the fonction recognised the good coordinate. About the scales, I check it and it is okay

Comment: Ok, therefore, there is nothing wrong with the code, it only returns back to the Template pieces in which normalized 2D cross correlation (NCC) is not working on some of the pieces,  I recommend to fill the black pixels in the Template pieces with mean of all pixel intensity. Beside, you can try other methods (other than NCC) like sum of squared of pixel difference to check the similarity between Template and Search picture. So piece pictures can be non-rectangular with no black area

Comment: Hello, is im2gray works in 2020a ?  because i couldn't run these codes unless i change im2gray to rgb2gray.

Comment: And why output images are still in rgb despite the fact that we used im2gray.

Comment: yes im2gray is working on 2020a, that is the reason why I am use it. As I say, after the NCC, I draw a rectangle where we have the correlation between the two image and I draw on a RGB image